# How to reduce the distance between legends and chart on pentaho cde?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

It seems the size/width of legend part is fixed, so when the labels are too long, they are cut.

So I want to reduce the distance between the legend part and the chart (because as on the screenshot, there's enough space to show long labels).

Tried almost every option avaible on pie chart component, still stuck with this problem :(

Anyone has solved the same problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the legend properties legendOverflow, legendItemSize and legendSizeMax? legendOverflow has a value "collapse" as an alternative to "trim".

Comment: I have to choose CLIP for legendOverflow, otherwise the whold legend disappears when the labels are too long. Also tried with legendItemSize and SizeMax, not the right ones though.

Comment: LegendSizeMax:70% should reserve more area for the legend. I also set Margins and Content Margins to 0, but when I tried here, it didn't seem to do much for the pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a 100% certain solution for you, but this is how I was able to get some decent length for legend items:

**Margins:0**

**Content Margins:0**

These reduce the dead whitespace in most chart types.

**LegendSize:x%**  Set a fixed percentage of the chart for the legend. In your example, 70-80% should work.

**LegendSizeMax:x%** If you want the legend size to shrink when there are few items, use this one instead.

**LegendItemSize:y%** where y = 100 / number of columns you normally have for the legend. This stretches the legend item width. If the live chart has less columns, you're stuck with empty space, if it has more, you lose those extra items.

This is less than ideal, but should work when you have similar item counts in typical use. A more complex way to fix this would be to calculate the number of items post-fetch and then set these properties accordingly.

Diethard Steiner has a blog on how to set CCC chart properties in code:
http://diethardsteiner.github.io/ctools/2015/03/23/CDE-Global-CCC-Properties.html

You can use the examples there to create a function that updates legend item sizes post-fetch, if you haven't already.

From my version here are the relevant property names:

```
function initGlobalCccProperties(dashboard, chartDefinition){
// get chart definition
// var cccOptions = this.chartDefinition;
var cccOptions = chartDefinition;
var myDashboard = dashboard; 

// standard ccc properties
var globalCccProperties = {
      legendAlign: "center"
    , legendItemSize: "50%"
    , legendOverflow: "collapse"
    , legendPosition: "bottom"
    , legendSizeMax: "80%"
    , legendFont: '14px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif'
    , margins: 0
    , contentMargins: "0"
    , paddings: 10
};
```